# Is there any way to use jquery code inside razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is my jQuery code with Razor:

```
    $("#GroupC_grup_name").attr('value', '@foreach (SelectListItem sel in (SelectList)ViewData["Gruplar"]){ @sel.Text }')
    $("#GroupC_id").attr('value', '@foreach(SelectListItem sel in (SelectList)ViewData["Gruplar"]){ @sel.Value }')
```

I want to merge these together, as in I dont want to call for `ViewData["Gruplar"]` twice.

Can I do something like this?

```
 @foreach(SelectListItem sel in (SelectList)ViewData["Gruplar"]){
     @:$("#GroupC_grup_name").attr('value', '@sel.Text');
     @:$("#GroupC_id").attr('value', '@sel.Value');
 }
```

I've tried everything I can think of but still can't achieve what I want.

Comment: Your code is a little confusing as your values in both examples are going to be strange. In the first example you're just outputting all the values from the list into the element attribute `value` in the second example you're setting all the values one at a time but it will always be the last value that is set. What is it you're trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @BuildStarted this selectlist only contains 1 item.. so it will not be overwrited. Please read the topic carefully. I wanna learn if i can put some jquery code inside `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> @Razor { **jQuery** } </script>` thats my issue to solve. That selectlist up there is only an example of usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read it carefully and understand what you want to do. However your example is what is confusing. (it seems to everyone that answered)

What you've done in the second example should work just fine you could wrap your jQuery in a `<text></text>` element if that helps as well. If there's only ever one value you could just

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    @{ var x = ((SelectList)ViewData["Gruplar"]).First(); } 
    $("#GroupC_grup_name").attr('value', '@x.Text');
    $("#GroupC_id").attr('value', '@x.Value');
</script>
```

There are any number of ways you could accomplish razor within jquery. It's basically the same as razor with html.

It you want to *execute* razor on the client side then that's not going to happen. Razor is executed before it gets sent to the client.

Answer (score 7):

The code you suggest should work, the code below uses a string array instead of a `SelectList` but the principle should be be the same, the code below has been tested and works -

```
@{String[] testarr = {"hello","bye"};}
@foreach(String sel in testarr){
 @:$("#GroupC_grup_name").attr('value', '@sel');
 @:$("#GroupC_id").attr('value', '@sel');
}
```

Comment: I don't think that he wanted to overwrite `value`attribute for `#GroupC_grup_name` X number of times..

Comment: first of all i will not overwrite with the action that im gonna do! Also my selectlist only for carrying data value and text fields seperately, its a list **yes** but it only contains **1** item. So what i was trying is injecting some `jquery code` inside `razor` and thanks `@ipr101` its working with a `string array` with some overwriting as `@jgauffin` said it overwrites! so it should be like (`@sel.Value` to `GroupC_id` and `@sel.Text` to `GroupC_grup_name`) also if u can show a way to do it with a data carrier like `ViewData["Gruplar"]` i'd like to know it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to update the elements when a SELECT item is selected?

Create a regular select list and add the following jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#selectListId').change(function() {
        $selectedItem = $("option:selected", this);
        $("#GroupC_grup_name").val(selectedItem.html());
        $("#GroupC_id").val(selectedItem.val());
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: ur code is worthy but this is not my issue!
umm i think im being misunderstood.
selectlist has nothing to do but getting my values here..
im trying to add jquery code inside razor thats my issue is there a way to do that? its not important if i use a selectlist or a model to retrive some data.

Comment: It's very important to know what you want to do since Razor code is run in the webserver and the jQuery code is run in the webbrowser. they can not work together. Razor can only generate jQuery code (that later will be run in the browser)